# Is there a function in java to check if any json attribute is null?

Tags: java, json, null, gson

I have a message in `JSON` format that I converted to a `JSONObject`, and I have around 30 mandatory fields that I have to check for whether they're null or not. If one of these mandatory fields are null, I will discard the message, however other fields can be null without needing to discard the message. **Is there any efficient way I can do this without going through each and every field and using `isNull()` ?**

Also, the JSON objects are nested, so a simple `anyNull()` function would not work since it would only return if the object itself is null and not if the variables themselves are null.

I tried using gson to convert the message to a POJO, and created classes for 10 objects

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
Message message = gson.fromJson(msg, Message.class);
```

but since many classes are nested (and one of which is an array of objects) using simple null checkers don't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually speaking your question is not very clear because you're using a word of "message" that refers your particular class, but can also be more generic referring sent/received messages.

So something like for JSON elements in memory:

```java
public static void failOnNullRecursively(final JsonElement jsonElement) {
    if ( jsonElement.isJsonNull() ) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("null!");
    }
    if ( jsonElement.isJsonPrimitive() ) {
        return;
    }
    if ( jsonElement.isJsonArray() ) {
        for ( final JsonElement element : jsonElement.getAsJsonArray() ) {
            failOnNullRecursively(element);
        }
        return;
    }
    if ( jsonElement.isJsonObject() ) {
        for ( final Map.Entry<String, JsonElement> e : jsonElement.getAsJsonObject().entrySet() ) {
            failOnNullRecursively(e.getValue());
        }
        return;
    }
    throw new AssertionError(jsonElement);
}
```

or JSON documents in streams:

```java
public final class FailOnNullJsonReader
        extends JsonReader {

    private FailOnNullJsonReader(final Reader reader) {
        super(reader);
    }

    public static JsonReader create(final Reader reader) {
        return new FailOnNullJsonReader(reader);
    }

    @Override
    public void nextNull() {
        throw new IllegalStateException(String.format("null at %@!", getPath()));
    }

}
```

Both of them will throw on `null`. But it also seems that you want to validate `Message` instances:

> If one of these mandatory fields are null, I will discard the message, however other fields can be null without needing to discard the message.

So this tells why the above null-checks won't fit your needs. What you're looking for is [JSR-303](https://beanvalidation.org/2.0/). It won't be that efficient as you might want to want it to be (message instances are deserialized, validation takes time and resources too), but it might be efficient from the coding perspective:

```java
final Set<ConstraintViolation<V>> violations = validator.validate(message);
if ( !violations.isEmpty() ) {
    throw new ConstraintViolationException(violations);
}
```

or even integrate it right into Gson so that it serves middleware:

```java
public final class PostReadTypeAdapterFactory<V>
        implements TypeAdapterFactory {

    private final Predicate<? super TypeToken<?>> supports;
    private final BiConsumer<? super TypeToken<V>, ? super V> onRead;

    private PostReadTypeAdapterFactory(final Predicate<? super TypeToken<?>> supports, final BiConsumer<? super TypeToken<V>, ? super V> onRead) {
        this.supports = supports;
        this.onRead = onRead;
    }

    public static <V> TypeAdapterFactory create(final Predicate<? super TypeToken<?>> supports, final BiConsumer<? super TypeToken<V>, ? super V> onRead) {
        return new PostReadTypeAdapterFactory<>(supports, onRead);
    }

    @Override
    @Nullable
    public <T> TypeAdapter<T> create(final Gson gson, final TypeToken<T> typeToken) {
        if ( !supports.test(typeToken) ) {
            return null;
        }
        final TypeAdapter<T> delegate = gson.getDelegateAdapter(this, typeToken);
        return new TypeAdapter<T>() {
            @Override
            public void write(final JsonWriter out, final T value)
                    throws IOException {
                delegate.write(out, value);
            }

            @Override
            public T read(final JsonReader in)
                    throws IOException {
                final T readValue = delegate.read(in);
                @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
                final V value = (V) readValue;
                @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
                final TypeToken<V> valueTypeToken = (TypeToken<V>) typeToken;
                onRead.accept(valueTypeToken, value);
                return readValue;
            }
        };
    }

}
```

```java
public final class Jsr303Support {

    private Jsr303Support() {
    }

    public static <V> TypeAdapterFactory createTypeAdapterFactory(final Validator validator) {
        return PostReadTypeAdapterFactory.<V>create(
                typeToken -> typeToken.getRawType().isAnnotationPresent(Validate.class),
                (typeToken, value) -> {
                    final Set<ConstraintViolation<V>> violations = validator.validate(value);
                    if ( !violations.isEmpty() ) {
                        throw new ConstraintViolationException(violations);
                    }
                }
        );
    }

}
```

```java
@Target(ElementType.TYPE)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface Validate {
}
```

And the test (using Lombok for brevity):

```java
@Validate
@AllArgsConstructor
@EqualsAndHashCode
@ToString
final class Message {

    @NotNull
    final String foo;

    @NotNull
    final String bar;

    @NotNull
    final String baz;

}
```

```java
public final class Jsr303SupportTest {

    private static final Validator validator;

    static {
        try ( final ValidatorFactory validatorFactory = Validation.buildDefaultValidatorFactory() ) {
            validator = validatorFactory.getValidator();
        }
    }

    public static final Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
            .disableHtmlEscaping()
            .disableInnerClassSerialization()
            .registerTypeAdapterFactory(Jsr303Support.createTypeAdapterFactory(validator))
            .create();

    @Test
    public void test() {
        Assertions.assertEquals(new Message("1", "2", "3"), gson.fromJson("{\"foo\":\"1\",\"bar\":\"2\",\"baz\":\"3\"}", Message.class));
        final ConstraintViolationException ex = Assertions.assertThrows(ConstraintViolationException.class, () -> gson.fromJson("{\"foo\":\"1\",\"bar\":null,\"baz\":\"3\"}", Message.class));
        Assertions.assertEquals(1, ex.getConstraintViolations().size());
    }

}
```

And finally, probably the most efficient (in terms of reading JSON stream), but very limited whencompared to JSR-303 (and **NOT** working in Gson because Gson does not propagate null-checking to downstream (de)serializers), way that could replace `@NotNull` with a similar "functional" annotation:

```java
public final class NotNullTypeAdapterFactory
        implements TypeAdapterFactory {

    // note no external access
    private NotNullTypeAdapterFactory() {
    }

    @Override
    public <T> TypeAdapter<T> create(final Gson gson, final TypeToken<T> typeToken) {
        final TypeAdapter<T> delegate = gson.getAdapter(typeToken);
        return new TypeAdapter<T>() {
            @Override
            public void write(final JsonWriter out, @Nullable final T value)
                    throws IOException {
                if ( value == null ) {
                    throw new IllegalArgumentException(typeToken + " with null");
                }
                delegate.write(out, value);
            }

            @Override
            public T read(final JsonReader in)
                    throws IOException {
                @Nullable
                final T value = delegate.read(in);
                if ( value == null ) {
                    throw new IllegalArgumentException(typeToken + " with null at " + in.getPath());
                }
                return value;
            }
        };
    }

}
```

```java
@AllArgsConstructor
@EqualsAndHashCode
@ToString
final class Message {

    @JsonAdapter(NotNullTypeAdapterFactory.class)
    final String foo;

    @JsonAdapter(NotNullTypeAdapterFactory.class)
    final String bar;

    @JsonAdapter(NotNullTypeAdapterFactory.class)
    final String baz;

}
```

```java
public final class NotNullTypeAdapterFactoryTest {

    public static final Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
            .disableHtmlEscaping()
            .disableInnerClassSerialization()
            .create();

    @Test
    public void test() {
        Assertions.assertEquals(new Message("1", "2", "3"), gson.fromJson("{\"foo\":\"1\",\"bar\":\"2\",\"baz\":\"3\"}", Message.class));
        final IllegalArgumentException ex = Assertions.assertThrows(IllegalArgumentException.class, () -> gson.fromJson("{\"foo\":\"1\",\"bar\":null,\"baz\":\"3\"}", Message.class));
        Assertions.assertEquals("whatever here, the above does not work anyway", ex.getMessage());
    }

}
```

The third, JSR-303, looks like the best for you.